# Discontinuity of $\frac{1+\tan x}{1-\tan x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

> I have to find the discontinuity of the function $$y=\frac{1+\tan
>  x}{1-\tan x}.$$

It reduces to $\tan(\pi/4+x)$. However the answer says that there is no value for which $y=-1$.

I can't understand. Please help!!

Comment: Sorry I meant that the function never attains the value y=-1 @S.Panja-1729

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 See this http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%281-tan+x%29%2F%281%2Btan+x%29%3D-1

Comment: So what's that got to do with discontinuities? You are wasting people's time by not editing your question to state what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If you write $f(x) = \frac{1+x}{1-x}$ and $g(x) = \tan x$, then your function is $h(x)=(f\circ g)(x)$. This function can have a discontinuity wherever $g$ does, and also wherever $g$ takes a value which is a point of discontinuity of $f$.